# Bind a Label's BackColor a Hex color value from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm looking to get a BackColor of Label in ASP.NET Form and Change this label's Color with this value 
is that possible ?

```
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" BackColor='<%# System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Eval(Container.DataItem,"BgColor").ToString())%>'></asp:Label>
```

thanks.

Comment: you title and your question seem to not be in sync. You are trying to load the "ForeColor" or "BackColor" for the label from the database? What format is the color stored in the database, hex or name?

Comment: well, thanks for your comment, im sorry im looking for BackColor :D and i save it as Hex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using FromHtml:

```
<%# System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(Eval("BgColor")%>
```

Answer (score 7):

//Label, setting forecolor by HexaColor

```
lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#E93301");
```

or

//Label, setting forecolor by color Name

```
lblResult.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try,

```
<asp:Label 
     ID="Label2" 
     runat="server" 
     Text="Label" 
     BackColor='<%# System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Eval("BgColor").ToString())%>'>
</asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

the format is 3300FF in database

```
'<%# System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Eval("BgColor").ToString())%>'
```

but tha label display none color

Comment: 'System.Drawing.Color' does not contain a definition for 'FromHtml'

Answer (score 0):

you should used ColorHex like : #602A4D
And not used .Tostring() to this code :

```html
BackColor='<%# System.Drawing.Color.FromName(Eval("BgColor"))%>'>
```